# redirect user after update in class based view in django

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views, django-1.11

I'm using Django 1.11.

I'm using Class based view for update profile page, to updated auth user profile info.

**myapp/accounts/views.py**

```
class UpdateProfile(UpdateView):
    model = User
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    template_name = 'accounts/update.html'

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.request = None

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return self.request.user
```

This works fine for updating profile. But after update, it gives error

```
No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model.
```

I followed some YouTube tutorials [here](https://youtu.be/D9Xd6jribFU) which is using method based view and `form.py` to generate form, There I can check for request method and call `form.save()` and then redirect user to profile page (probably index).

**1. How can I do I check if data updated and then redirect user to `index` class in my class?**

**2. Is this method suitable for editing data using `pk`?**

I also want to generate flash message after updation for which I can use

```
messages.success(request, "Profile updated")
```

**3. Since class is not have request object, how to use `messages` in class based view?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `get_success_url` method.

```
def get_success_url(self):
    messages.success(self.request, 'Profile updated')
    return '/' # or whatever url you want to redirect to
```

The object request is in the `self`. Note that i don't understand why in your init you're doing `self.request = None`.

Comment: should I remove `__init__` if it's of no use, as this was copied from you answer on my previous question and you have edited your answer there.

Comment: hum i didn't writte any ```__init__()``` in my other answer, but yes, you can remove it

Comment: actually yes remove it

Comment: your return statement `return '/'` will redirect user to base url. How to redirect to another class based view in the same app say `Class ProfileView(TemaplateView):` or Classview of another app?

Comment: well you can use the urlreverse module of django. Some doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse